# Kendo ui /GANTT, Turn off popup window

Tags: php, mysql, kendo-ui

Guys are you able to help me to hide/disable just a popup box when double click on tasks?
http://demos.telerik.com/php-ui/gantt/index

I could add`->editable(false);` just below:

```
// gantt
$gantt = new \Kendo\UI\Gantt('gantt');
$gantt->dataSource($tasks)
      ->dependencies($dependencies)
      ->height(650)
      ->addView(
          '',
          array('type' => 'week', 'selected' => false),
          'month'
      )
      ->addColumn($idColumn, $titleColumn, $startColumn, $endColumn)
      ->showWorkHours(false)
      ->showWorkDays(true)
      ->snap(false)
      ->editable(false);
```

But then I cannot edit anything.
Any clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any methods to diable it directly, but you could do a workaroud using the `edit` method, which attaches a js event on the double click according to the [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/php/Kendo/UI/Gantt#methods-edit).
I think, if you add something simple like this, it should work:

```
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

If not, you could do something similar to prevent the event from firing.

Comment: Are you able to help me do the same thing like here but in php:
http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/apEYa

For this one:
http://demos.telerik.com/php-ui/gantt/index4

Comment: @mark1212 So what is your goal? What you want to achieve?

Comment: The goal is to prevent open popup modal windows when dbl click on tasks. Thats all.

Comment: But in the dojo you linked above, it works nicely. If you want to do this in php, you can attach the same function at that side. But there isn't any php function to do this. You can only do this with a JS workaround.